# Check for updates on every startup

Tags: android, updates

I have build my very first application to Android and I want now to let the application to check my server for new updates when the user starts the application; if the version in the APK filename (for example `weather-right-now-11.apk`) is different with the actual version, prompt user to download the new update. How can I accomplish this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this to your main activity :

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "OnResume", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        super.onResume();
    }
```

and add your action in this function. `onResume` run on every start of activity.

you must have a server that connect to it and check version of application and download it, you can check your version with this :

```
getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                context.getApplicationInfo().packageName, 0).versionCode;
```

you can use [tcp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) or [udp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol) packet to connect to server and check your last version. This is a link that you can learn about tcp :

- http://systembash.com/content/a-simple-java-tcp-server-and-tcp-client/

Comment: Thanks but how do I connect to my website trough this function to check the version? I started to create Android applications last night so I'm pretty new in this area.

Comment: Thanks but I your edit was the same as stephendnickolas answer. I know now how I check the applications version but what about to connect to the server and compare the version with the filename's version?

Comment: Thanks but I can't find anything on Google when I'm searching for `eclipse android tcp connection` that can solve my problem and I'm not understand a thing of, without help :/

Comment: post was edited. you must search about "tcp java" and "udp java"

Comment: Thanks but I will stop working with the Android application for now though. It's too hard! I don't even know how to create the .java file inside my project!

Comment: if you don't need to use an application to do this, you can use a simple way. Build a page in your site and refer to that with using a webView. like this : http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-webview.html
I try to answer your question, accept it

Comment: I'm very happy that you are trying to help me but I'm a very huge beginner in this area. Many thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 1):

You can get the current version code of your application with the following:

```
    /*
     * Try to get the current version code from the package manager.
     */
    int currentVersionCode;
    try {
        currentVersionCode = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                context.getApplicationInfo().packageName, 0).versionCode;
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        // Shouldn't ever happen - but log anyway
        return;
    }
```

You'd then need to setup some methods to check with the server when your application starts, either in onCreate or onResume. Note: I'd suggest using an AsyncTask or separate thread to do this,